# Find the difference in weight of figs before and after they are dried.

Tags: arithmetic

One kg of dried figs costs $11.25$   while  one  kg  of  fresh  figs  costs $9$.  A farmer has 20 kg of fresh figs.  What is the difference in weight of the farmer's figs before and after they are dried?

Comment: Question is not clear in the sense of rate of evaporation of the figs.

Comment: There is no rate of evaporation in this question.

Comment: Do we assume that a single fig is worth the same dry as it is fresh?

Comment: Ok you can assume

Comment: @arther please check this. Let's say that there are 11.25 figs in a kg. Adding water to them makes tJen heavier: 9/kg . Y kg of dried figs by this measure would be Y*11.25 figs. This corresponds to Y*11.25/9, Y = 0.8kg (Does this make sense?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ kg of dried fig + $y$ kg of water = $1$ kg of fresh fig

$11,25x = 9,0$ -> It means that we are interested in the solid part. Water does not care.

$x = \frac{9,0}{11,25} = 0,8$

So, our initial formula is

$0,8$ kg of dried fig + $0,2$ kg of water = $1$ kg of fresh fig